# spring boot vs tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat8

We currently running an app on production on tomcat  8.0.44.
We migrated our app to work on spring boot v2.0.4 (embedded tomcat) and now we need to upload it to production (instead of the tomcat implementation)

Could someone share his experience regarding this transfer? 
Any impact noticed? All aspects (load, performance, etc), any downsides?
What should we consider when doing this transfer? (load test is problematic due to the nature of our application)

Also, I understood that spring boot can run as executable (currently not implemented on QA). What are the benefits of using it? is it preferable as to using java to run spring boot (the regular way)? any downsides?

Thanks,
Hila

Comment: if you've tested and covered all the migration steps (configurations, container jars vs dependencies) then you should be good to go. it's mostly a convenience thing. and yes, the convention is to produce an executable jar

Comment: the (depending on perspective) downside is not being able to put multiple apps in one tomcat